# How to read international phonetics alphabet with AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer, phonetics

I'm working on an iOS app, and I have some words in phonetics, i want my iPhone say those words.

for example "tʃat" means "chat".

But AVSpeechSynthesizer can't speak it correctly. ʃ is not pronounced.

Did i miss something, do i need a third part or is this possible on iOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVSpeechSynthesizer doesn't support phonetics, just regular text, like this:

```
let string = "Hello, World!"
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: string)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.speakUtterance(utterance)
```

(code is lifted from http://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/)

The parameter to AVSpeechUtterance's init method is:

> string - A string containing text to be spoken.